# Is it possible to obtain a jwt refresh token using my server as sort of a proxy?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, access-token, jwt, auth0

I'm creating a system where there are agents that require refresh tokens to report data to the system.  The user would provision a token for an agent through my webapp.

I'm attempting to have my server pass on the request for the refresh token to my auth provider (auth0).   The flow is

1. user clicks "provision",
2. my server attempts to go to auth0 to get a token using the bearer token created for the client
3. I save the refresh token to my server's datastore
4. my server bundles the token with an agent package and it downloads to the client.

I'm getting hung up on step #2, though.  The server makes the call for the offline/refresh token with a valid bearer token, but the auth0 server comes back saying it wants a login and to go through the callback URL.

Not quite sure if my plan will work.   Is this feasible?

If this isn't feasible, is it safe to create my own refresh tokens for my agents using whatever jwt library to sign some token request, and then issue my own access tokens when the refresh token is presented?

edit:
I've modified the flow a bit so that I'm calling the request for the refresh token in my client.   I get a callback URL with either the refresh token itself or a grant code which I can pass back to my server.   It seems very unsafe having the refresh token in the browser URL!   The grant code seems a little safer, but I'm still in the same boat of not being able to get the refresh token on the server side.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around the problem you are trying to solve using the refresh token. FYI, in OAuth 2.0 refresh tokens are granted to clients (web application running in browser or mobile apps) and intended for use only with authorization servers (auth0) and never sent to resource server (your server application). Please explain your requirement with out any tokens/ authentication pieces. We can then look for a solution. Thank you, Soma.

Comment: @SomaYarlagadda we have data gathering agents which run without any user interface that need to be authenticated.   The plan is to obtain a refresh token, install that token into the agent allowing it to get an access token.

Answer (score 1):

Are these agents secure? To make things more clear, please define what technologies you are using for Client, Web Server and Agent (application).

You won't be able to retrieve refresh tokens on your web server. Refresh tokens are meant for long running clients to get an access_token, if the current one is expired. If your agents are secure, you could use Client Credentials Grant to get an access token. I think this flow would be at least as safe as having a refresh token on the Agent. Please let me know if this flow is an option.

Thank you,
Soma.